# DataFrame not being assigned given value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following class and the print statement returns an empty dataframe even though I'm sure my get_percent_change method is returning the values. I even tried just assigning test to three. Still, empty dataframe.

Is it something to do with the fact it's inside a class? Inside the init method? I tried using self.metrics too.

```
class options_metrics:
    def __init__(self, calls, puts):
        self.calls, self.puts = calls, puts
        self.calls = self.calls.drop(["Type"])
        self.puts = self.puts.drop(["Type"])

        metrics = pd.DataFrame()
        metrics['Perc_Chg_Vol_Call'], metrics['Perc_Chg_Open_Int_Call'] = self.get_percent_change(self.calls)

        metrics['Test'] = 3

        print(metrics)
        input()

    def get_percent_change(self, option_df):
        perc_changes = option_df.pct_change(axis=1)
        print(perc_changes)
        return (perc_changes.ix['Vol',1], perc_changes.ix['Open_Int',1])
```

Here is the output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Perc_Chg_Vol_Call, Perc_Chg_Open_Int_Call, Test]
Index: []
```

Comment: `metrics = pd.DataFrame()` -- where do you think you're adding data (rows) to this DataFrame?

Comment: I could've swore I've set values to an empty dataframe like this before, but I guess maybe it had rows already or the rows were initiated correctly through pandas before storing. 

I've switched it to a Series and that'll work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the DataFrame to a Series worked.